# Is there any way to add a line of code to all .html files?

Tags: php, html

I have 100 html files, and i want to add a line of code (at the end) to all of them.

How is this possible ?
Something like a script which appends that line into all html files

I tried searching but did not find anything.

Comment: Does the line go after the same previous line in all of them? Maybe some sort of grep / regex solution. I assume this is a one-off job? Not sure why you think htaccess would be involved, tbh.

Comment: You want a PHP Script ? or a Python script will be good for ?

Comment: Where do you want to add that line? Simply at the end? Anywhere within the existing markup structure?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for server side includes, .shtml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
<?php
$folder = '/path/to/html/files';
$line_to_add = '<p>your line/p>';

foreach (glob("$folder/*.html") as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    file_put_contents($file, $line_to_add . PHP_EOL . $contents);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is quite unclear, because you didn't specify where you are going to append this lane? Here is a starting point:

```
<?php

$path = '/path/to/html/files';
$code_to_add = '<p>This line was added by a script.</p>';

$files = scandir($path); //  get an array of all the files in the directory specified by $path.
foreach ($files as $file) { // Iterate over files
    if (substr($file, -5) == '.html') { // hecking if each file has a ".html" extension.
        $file_path = $path . '/' . $file;
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path); // read the contents
        file_put_contents($file_path, $file_contents . $code_to_add); // put new content, you can modify it.
    }
}

?>
```